# How to convert rows to columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, jooq

I have two database tables as below

```
site
id    |    name
1        Site One
2        Site Two
3        Site Three

asset_quantities
id   |   site_id   |  asset_type   | quantity
1           1             1              10
2           1             2              15
3           1             3              25
4           2             1              11
5           2             2              16
6           2             3              7
7           3             1              12
8           3             2              15
9           3             3              16
```

I want to write a SQL query that will sort results based on the 'quantity' column for a given asset type
E.g. I want to sort descending results based on the quantity for asset type 1 across all sites.
How would I frame the SQL query for a scenario like this?

Below is a sample result I want if I want descending order results for the quantity of asset type 1 across all sites

```
site_id  |   asset_type_1_qty   |   asset_type_2_qty  |  asset_type_3_qty 
   3                12                     15                  16
   2                11                     16                  7
   1                10                     15                  25
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the result? it would be clearer for us to understand want you want.

Comment: Shawn - I have updated the question with an example result I want

Comment: I have given the answer.Hope it would help for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that will do what you want in sqlserver. You should be able to adapt it to postgres.

I have two versions, one which hard codes the sort, the second which uses a parameter to decide what to sort by.

First create the data in temporary table variable

```
declare @s table(id int, site_id int, asset_type int, quantity int)
insert @s values (1,1,1,10)
,(2,1,2,15)
,(3,1,3,25)
,(4,2,1,11)
,(5,2,2,16)
,(6,2,3,7)
,(7,3,1,12)
,(8,3,2,15)
,(9,3,3,16)
```

First version with fixed column sort

```
select site_id, 
    max(case when asset_type=1 then quantity else 0 end) as q1,
    max(case when asset_type=2 then quantity else 0 end) as q2,
    max(case when asset_type=3 then quantity else 0 end) as q3
from @s 
group by site_id
order by 2 desc
```

Second version with parameter column sort

```
declare @assetsort int;
set @assetsort=3

select * from (
    select site_id, 
        max(case when asset_type=1 then quantity else 0 end) as q1,
        max(case when asset_type=2 then quantity else 0 end) as q2,
        max(case when asset_type=3 then quantity else 0 end) as q3
    from @s 
    group by site_id
) q 
order by 
    case @assetsort when 1 then q1 when 2 then q2 when 3 then q3 end desc
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is easy to implement this, just use a `self join`, as below:

```
select
    s1.site_id,
    s1.quantity as asset_type_1_qty,
    s2.quantity as asset_type_2_qty,
    s3.quantity as asset_type_3_qty
from
    asset_quantities s1
join
    asset_quantities s2 on s1.site_id=s2.site_id and s1.asset_type=1 and s2.asset_type=2
join
    asset_quantities s3 on s1.site_id=s3.site_id and s3.asset_type=3
order by
    s1.quantity desc
```

OK, there is a function called `crosstab` which can transform rows to columns, I think it would meet your needs perfectly, just as below:

```
postgres=# select * from asset_quantities;
 id | site_id | asset_type | quantity 
----+---------+------------+----------
  1 |       1 |          1 |       10
  2 |       1 |          2 |       15
  3 |       1 |          3 |       25
  4 |       2 |          1 |       11
  5 |       2 |          2 |       16
  6 |       2 |          3 |        7
  7 |       3 |          1 |       12
  8 |       3 |          2 |       15
  9 |       3 |          3 |       16
(9 rows)

postgres=# select * from crosstab(
'select
    site_id,
    asset_type,
    quantity
from
    asset_quantities order by site_id,asset_type'
) as result(site_id int,asset_type_1_qty int,asset_type_2_qty int,asset_type_3_qty int);
 site_id | asset_type_1_qty | asset_type_2_qty | asset_type_3_qty 
---------+------------------+------------------+------------------
       1 |               10 |               15 |               25
       2 |               11 |               16 |                7
       3 |               12 |               15 |               16
(3 rows)
```

Oh right, before you use the `crosstab` function, you should execute the clause below in PostgreSQL, otherwise you would get an error.

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Is there a way to make the query generic such that it can accommodate any number of asset types? At the moment I have only 3 asset types but the user can add upto 30 in the future. In that case, I wouldn't want to join 30 times as that will slow the query down significantly.

Comment: OK, let me think and give you a more perfect answer, just wait minutes.

Comment: @user1066568 I have updated my answer, I think it would solve your problem perfectly.Good luck !